# Passing data from Express to HTML (Pug) to display Chart.js

Tags: node.js, express, chart.js

I am new to web development so everything is kinda new to me especially the asynchronous code is pretty different from C language which I learned before.

I have been trying to pass values from Express to HTML to display the Chart but unfortunately after 2 days of tries and I m still unable to execute it correctly.

Let get to the codes straight:-

index.js

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.render('index', { var1: 'apple' });
})
```

index.pug

```
    //Codes simplified
    const chartData = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
        //label: 'My First dataset',   <--Default value which works
        label: var1,    <----I have tried {{var1}}, <<%= var1 >> none works

        data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45],
    }]
    };
```

I can pass value from Express to HTML(Pug) easily. But anything falls under the script for Chart it just won't work. As soon as I switch to the default value it works therefore the script is actually alright but my value passing method..which I'm still clueless what is the fault after hours of google searching.

If you need more info I can provide too. Thanks!

**Found the answer**
It should be **'!{var1}'** for Pug!

Answer (score 0):

{{var1}}, <<%= var1 >> are the syntaxes for Handlebars and EJS respectively.

for Pug it'll be **#{var1}**.

An example code snippet below

Read the HTML/template file and replace the identifier with chart data.

The pug file below.

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title my chart application
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    | **
    script(src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js')
    | **
    style.
      
  body
    canvas#test
    script.
      var data = {
         labels: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"],
         datasets: [
              {
                label: "My data",
                fillColor: "rgba(189,156,221,0.2)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(189,156,221,1)",
                pointColor: "rgba(189,156,221,1)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#111",
                pointHighlightFill: "#000",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(189,156,221,1)",
                data: #{myChartInfo}
              }
            ]
         };
      
      var ctx = document.getElementById("test").getContext("2d");
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data);
```

Nodejs

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile('index.pug', 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        const chartData = 'some data';
        const result = data.toString('utf8').replace('#{myChartInfo}', JSON.stringify(chartData));
        res.write(result);
        res.end();
    });
}).listen(3000);
```

The **#{myChartInfo}** in the HTML/templating engine is replaced with the data at the server-side.

Comment: With a quick test by replacing the var1 with #{var1} and it just wont show the chart. Not really sure why but i will try with the .replace method.

Comment: Got it to work finally! It is  
**'!{var1};'**  !!  Pug is very different therefore I have to search more specifically for Pug.